Trying to solve second-order nonlinear BVP with Dirichlet and Robin boundary conditions using finite difference method
The ODE I have is $$u'' + \exp(u)u' = \mu \sin({2 \pi x}), \ u(0) = 1, \ u'(1)+(u(1))^3=0,$$
where $\mu$ is just a parameter that will be used to investigate the solution to the function later.
I'm trying to solve this ODE using a second-order finite difference scheme using $N+1$ equally spaced nodes.
The function is defined on the interval $[0,1]$, I've defined the spacing between points as $h = 1/n$, the endpoints of the interval correspond to the nodes $x_0 = 0$ and $x_n = 1$, so each node is given by $x_i = x_0 + ih = ih, i = 0,1,.\ldots,n$.
Then, this is where I get a bit unsure if what I'm doing is correct as the notes I'm referring too are limited to simpler problems. But I write the finite difference approximation of the ODE: $$\frac{u_{i+1} - 2u_i - u_{i-1}}{h^2} + \exp({u_i})\frac{u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}}{2h} = \mu \sin{(2 \pi x_i)}$$
Then I multiply through by $2h^2$ and simplify: $$(2+h\exp(u_i))u_{i+1} - (2+h\exp(u_i))u_{i-1}-4u_i = \mu \sin{(2\pi x_i)}2h^2$$
So, from my knowledge the difference equations are this approximation at each node so for $i = 1,2,...,n-1$, but then because of the Robin boundary condition I add an extra equation, namely, $$u_{i-2}-4u_{i-2}+3u_i=-2h(u_n)^3,$$
which I derived from the Robin boundary condition using the second-order backwards difference formula for $u'$. Is this right or how would I go about tackling this?
I then believe since this is a nonlinear BVP I need to use the Jacobian matrix next, before using the Newton-Raphson Method to start solving this (which I will do in Matlab), which is given by $J_{ij} = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial u_j}$. Is this also correct, as when I start differentiating I still have the nonlinear term?
And finally, what would be a suitable guess for the solution to the BVP to initialise the Newton-Raphson method?

The Ghost Point Method is the best way to incorporate these BCs. Here is an answer with some details.

Your ODE is overdetermined and cannot satisfy all three conditions you've given simultaneously.

Sorry, there was a mistake with the Robin boundary condition, it was meant to be a plus symbol not an equals, fixed now.

@yen Correct is $$u_{xx}\approx \frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i\color{red}{+}u_{i-1}}{h^2}$$

There is an analytical solution:
\begin{align}
&u(x)=\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}+u'(1)+\exp u(1)\right)x-\frac{\mu}{(2\pi)^2}\sin(2\pi x)\&-\log\left(\frac 1e-\int_0^x\exp\left{\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}+u'(1)+\exp u(1)\right)x'-\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi x')\right}\mathrm dx'\right),
\end{align}
where $u(1)$ and $u'(1)$ satisfy
\begin{align}
u'(1)+u(1)^3=0,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&u(1)=\frac{\mu}{2\pi}+u'(1)+\exp u(1)\&-\log\left(\frac 1e-\int_0^1\exp\left{\left(\frac{\mu}{2\pi}+u'(1)+\exp u(1)\right)x'-\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi x')\right}\mathrm dx'\right).
\end{align}

Yes you will need to solve this system with something akin to Newton’s method (either your own, or a pre-existing one, such as fsolve in MATLAB).
Initial guesses for BVPs are an art as much as a science.  You don’t know at this stage if solutions are even unique.  One thing you could try is finding the exact solution for $\mu = 0$, which you can do implicitly, although I imagine you will still need to determine some constants using a root finding method.

Given the following Nonlinear Boundary Value Problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
u''(x)+u'(x)\exp(u(x))=\mu\sin(2\,\pi\,x)\\
u(0)=1\\
u'(1)+u^3(1)=0\\
\end{cases},
\qquad
x\in[0,1]
$$
first I would take a look at Mathematica to get a basis for comparison:
μ = 12;
usol = NDSolveValue[{u''[x] + u'[x] Exp[u[x]] == μ Sin[2 π x],
                     u[0] == 1, u'[1] + u[1]^3 == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}];
p1 = Plot[usol[x], {x, 0, 1}]

Then I would discretize the domain into $n+1$ equally spaced points:
$$
x_1=0,
\qquad
\Delta x= 1/n,
\qquad
x_{k+1}=x_k+\Delta x,
\qquad
k=1,2,\dots,n
$$
and I would construct the respective system of equations of order $n+1$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{u_k-2u_{k-1}+u_{k-2}}{\Delta x^2}+\frac{u_k-u_{k-1}}{\Delta x}\,\exp(u_k)=\mu\sin(2\,\pi\,x_k)\\
u_1=1\\
\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{\Delta x}+u_{n+1}^3=0\\
\end{cases},
\quad
k=3,4,\dots,n+1
$$
which can be solved with Newton-Raphson method with first-attempt unitary solution:
n = 100;
Δx = 1./n;
X = Table[k, {k, 0, 1, Δx}];

U[k_] := ToExpression[StringJoin["u", ToString[k]]]
V[k_] := (U[k] - U[k - 1]) / Δx
W[k_] := (U[k] - 2 U[k - 1] + U[k - 2]) / Δx^2

eqns = Join[Table[W[k] + V[k] Exp[U[k]] - μ Sin[2 π X[[k]]], {k, 3, n + 1}],
            {U[1] - 1}, {V[n + 1] + U[n + 1]^3}];

var = Table[{U[k], 1}, {k, 1, n + 1}];
Y = FindRoot[eqns, var][[All, 2]];
p2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Y}]]

or it can be traced back to an optimization problem (no first-attempt solution needed here):
var = Table[U[k], {k, 1, n + 1}];
Y = NMinimize[Total[eqns^2], var][[2, All, 2]];
p2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Y}]]

where under the hood there are many implemented methods, including DifferentialEvolution, RandomSearch, SimulatedAnnealing, NelderMead, which will be applied depending on the case.
Therefore, all that remains is to show the two graphs in the same plane:
Show[p1, p2]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$
to understand that we are on the right track; increasing $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the dots will adhere better.

Here is a MATLAB implementation that just uses finite differences of accuracy 2: Finite difference coefficient
%% Clear workspace
clc
clear
close all
format long

%% Parameter
mu = +12;
% Number of samples on x-axis
n = 501;

x = linspace(0, 1, n)';
% Initial solution guess
u0 = 1.0 - 0.2*x;

%% Solve nonlinear equations
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','none','FunctionTolerance',1e-9);
[sol,fval,~,output] = fsolve(@(u) u_equations(u,x,mu), u0, options);

%% Visualize solution
figure
plot(x, sol)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('u(x)')
title(sprintf('Solution u(x) (%s=%.2f)','\mu',mu))
grid on

%% Local functions
function F = u_equations(u, x, mu)
    n = length(u);
    h = mean(diff(x));
    F = zeros(size(u));
    % Initial value
    F(1) = u(1) - 1.0;

    % Central finite difference
    k = 2:n-1;
    % Accuracy 2
    uxx = (u(k-1) - 2*u(k) + u(k+1)) / h^2;
    ux  = (-u(k-1) + u(k+1)) / (2*h);
    lhs = uxx + exp(u(k)) .* ux;
    rhs = mu * sin(2*pi*x(k));
    F(k)= lhs - rhs;

    % Backward finite difference (Accuracy 2)
    ux_back = (1/2*u(end-2) - 2*u(end-1) + 3/2*u(end)) / h;
    F(end) = ux_back + u(end)^3;
end


See also MSE_Q5004708
